# My vba IE scraper program won't click the go button for some reason

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

so I'm trying to learn how to interact with html using vba and I'm using this code:

```
Sub IEScraper()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim link As HTMLLinkElement
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate ("duckduckgo.com")

    Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.document.getElementById("search_form_input_homepage").Value = _
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
    ie.document.getElementById("search_form_input_homepage").Click
End Sub
```

It works up until the click line, where the page just won't click. No error pops up and the code ends but the button won't be clicked. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
ie.document.getElementById("search_button_homepage").Click
```